# Sum over subpart of MiniZinc array

Tags: sum, minizinc

In MiniZinc, I have a model with variables in a Day domain and in a Timesteps domain. For this example I have 3 days and 36 timesteps (2 hours each; so each day consists of 12 timesteps of 2 hours). (I have decided these days and timesteps in an earlier script).

The problem is that for each day I want to sum over the timesteps belonging to that day. So day 1: 1 .. 12 timesteps, day 2: 13 .. 24 timesteps, day 3: 25 .. 36 timesteps. Doing multiplications in the index specification in `sum` is not allowed in MiniZinc. How can I do these partial sums?

Here is what I tried:

```
set of int: Days = 1..3; 
set of int: Timesteps = 1..36;

array[Timesteps] of var -1.0..1.0: X; 
array[Days] of var -1.0..1.0: Y;

constraint forall(d in Days)(Y[d] = sum(t in (1 + (d-1)*12)..d*12)(X[t]));
```

Comment: Do you mean that you get an error when running this model? If so, what error message and what version of MiniZinc and what FlatZinc solver? I don't get any errors when running MiniZinc v2.5.5 and Gecode solver. However, the Chuffed solver yield an error since it don't support Float variables.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am running MiniZinc from python and the error wasn't that informative. In the end the issue wasn't in the constraint.. I had a mismatch between amount of days and timesteps.